# how can I get data in the table cell that is checked after submit

Tags: php, sql, mysql

can someone give me help, please.

here's my basic html

```
<form action="addSomething.php" method="POST">
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Add Data</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>  
</tr>

 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="sample1" /> </td>
  <td class="desc">Newbie</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="sample1" /> </td>
<td class="desc">Pro</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="sample1"/> </td>
<td class="desc" > Master </td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>

<br/>
     <input type="submit" name="add" value="SUBMIT"/>
.....
```

how can I get the one with the class "desc" and the column for quantity that is checked  after submitting the form

because the only I can add when querying in mysql is the value of checkbox  but I want also the value of the data in "Description" column and "Quantity" column

In my *addSomething.php* the code I have is

```
 if(isset($_POST['add']))
      {

           foreach($_POST['data'] as $value)
           {

           $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (column1) VALUES('$value');"

                //query stuff
            }

      }
```

what I will do , Any hints guys?

Answer (score 1):

you can give your checkboxes different values

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="newbie" />
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="pro" />
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="master" />
```

and then in addSomething.php define an array

```
$names = array('newbie'=>'Newbie', 'pro'=>'Pro', 'master'=>'Master');
```

and use it in your sql

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
  {
       foreach($_POST['data'] as $value)
       {
           $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (column1) VALUES ('".$names[$value]."');";
        }
  }
```

this applies only if you don't want users to edit the decription and quantity on the frontend. if you do, you need to put inputs in there and give them unique names.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise something along the lines of:

```
<form action="addSomething.php" method="POST">
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Add Data</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>  
</tr>

 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[0]" value="sample1" /> </td>
  <td class="desc">Newbie<input type="checkbox" name="desc[0]" value="Newbie" /></td>
  <td>2<input type="checkbox" name="quan[0]" value="2" /></td>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[1]" value="sample1" /> </td>
<td class="desc">Pro<input type="checkbox" name="desc[1]" value="Pro" /></td>
<td>1<input type="checkbox" name="quan[1]" value="1" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[2]" value="sample1"/> </td>
<td class="desc" > Master <input type="checkbox" name="desc[2]" value="Master" /></td>
<td>1<input type="checkbox" name="quan[2]" value="1" /></td>
</tr>

<br/>
     <input type="submit" name="add" value="SUBMIT"/>
...
```

with php

```
 if(isset($_POST['add']))
      {

           foreach($_POST['data'] as $i => $value) {
              $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc'][$i]);
              $quan = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quan'][$i]);
              $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (desc,quan) VALUES('$desc','$quan');"

                //query stuff
            }

      }
```

You have to explicitly number your fields in html to preserve associacion of data with checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is write Javascript that triggers an AJAX request to your server.

Otherwise, you won't be able to get values in prior submit.

Answer (score 0):

That, is by far, very inefficient. Executing a query for each field in your table.

Comment: +1, this is not the best way of doing what you want to do. Not at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to put the description in a hidden field or read the description from the database.
I suggest the later option.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include these values in a hidden input

`<input type="hidden" name="`whatever`" value="`whatever>`"`

as an example

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for your code is you create a javascript function and call it on submit of form :

```
<form action="addSomething.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return postVars()">
```

when you submit the form, this function will be called. create a 2 hidden forms like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="description" id="description">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="quantity">
```

give a unique id to your td s and pass the id to your js function. fill these inputs in your js function :

```
document.getElementById('description').value = document.getElementById('td_' + id + '_description').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('quantity').value = document.getElementById('td_' + id + '_quantity').innerHTML;
```

and in your server side just get description and quantity from $_POST.
hope it's been helpful ;)